# C GCC homebrew macOS

Tags: c, macos, gcc, homebrew

Суть такая, по умолчанию на маке gcc 4 версии. Я поставил через homebrew (там gcc8 C11 поддерживает), но почему-то homebrew не сделал линк на новый gcc и gcc --version выдаёт старый.... Как руками правильно сделать ссылку на новый gcc???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brew сделал новую команду, имя которой `gcc-8`
То есть что бы при работе с консолью у Вас появлялась новая версия стоит писать:

```
$ gcc-8 ...
```

Для простоты набора можно создать `alias`ы.

Должен предупредить, что при использовании `alias` Вам всё равно потребуется, скажем, в `makefile` указывать `gcc-8`

П.С. Устанавливал `gcc-8` и она не работала: любой скомпилированный код выдавал ошибку сегментирования, а отладчик указывал на самую первую строку файла. Возможно уже пофиксили.